# Ubuntu 16.04 can't rebuild mySQL

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to do a clean reinstall of mySQL on my local machine for various reasons. I have followed sever posts here and on stack. particularly followed [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763534/cannot-reinstall-mysql-server-after-its-purge) in detail, however every time I go through the steps I end at the same result.

```
Setting up mysql-client (5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.


        Setting up mysql-client (5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
     mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
      Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

    dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                              Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
    Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21) ...
    Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     mysql-server-5.7
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am absolutely stumped at this point...

Comment: what did systemctl say for mysql service? is it running?  what does the status say?

Comment: Unknown operation mysql.

Comment: service mysql status
* MySQL is stopped.

Comment: I'm following this forum, https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1763604&page=3 
but will forcing the reinstall help?

Comment: yes at this point force reinstalling will work, as i have no DBs built as of yet.

Comment: ok. then you should be safe to do the --force flag on the reinstall. I was concerned if there would be any DBs you need to do a backup, but according the the error, you never configured mysql.

Comment: so apt install mysql-server-5.7 --force ?

Comment: i write a post what to do. it may or may not help.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed earlier in the discussion in the post, I think you are safe to reinstall it. We should remove all traces of previous installation of mysql and then reinstall it.

`sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*`

If these were installed as part of the package dependencies for mysql,

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Then the important bit, this error could be caused because your distribution is not upgraded recently, or at least conflicts are not resolved properly. I would just upgrade Ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Now after this is done, you can try to install mysql as normal again. Hope this will work, please give a report. If it doesnt work we'll try another fix.

Here's a link to digital oceans installation for mysql. Though you could use MariaDB.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: should also note, at one point I had MariaDB over the top of my Mysql anything I need to do different?

Comment: so this is basically the same instructions I have been trying for a day now. the only addition is that I ran sudo apt-get remove --purge maria* as a precaution to make sure there were no mariaDB traces left either. after following these exact steps again I am getting the same result as the original post.

Comment: Okay. Let me think about another solution. What repo are installing from? MariaDB is a fork from MySQL. I should add.

Comment: i havent added any repos so I am not so sure. to be honest this is all a bit over my head at this point!

Comment: When you install MySQL, do you get any errors or is this the error you are getting after installing it?